# Registration form returning Server Error 500

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, execute

I've created a form where users input their registration details and it enters it into an SQL database using a query. However, I type in all the details, click submit and it return a server error 500. 
I'm new to binding & executing so probably slipped up with the format of the mysqli lines.

**registrationsubmit.php**

```
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

<?php

include 'registrationform.php';
include 'connection.php';
?>

<center>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['regsubmit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $user = $_POST['username'];    
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbhandle, $query = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Username, Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $firstname,$lastname,$user,$pass);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die('This username is already in use - Please choose another one');

 }else{
die('Error when preparing '.mysqli_error($dbhandle));
}
  Echo "Registration Successful - Press the Home button to return to the homepage.";

}
?>
</center>
```

Comment: u just hard coded bro ,are  you check for database connection

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully you will find redundant variable assignment. Try using this instead:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbhandle, "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Username, Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
```

Comment: I get a server error when I use that line of code mate